# Convert activated windows server 2012 std on Hyper-V guest to ESXI virtual machine

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v-server-2012, activation

I've activated **Windows Server 2012** on **Hyper-V** virtual machine (guest) and i want convert it to **VMware**  virtual machine on **ESXI** server

My question is

> "Can i do it without activate Windows again ?"

Comment: You don't have a key?

Answer (score 0):

No. The underlying virtual hardware seeing by Windows Server will have changed too much, requiring reactivation.

If you were moving between Hyper-V hosts or ESX hosts you could avoid it by exporting the guest and importing it on the destination. But between different hypervisors? Not that I know of.